# onlocationchanged called too late and not according to my requirement

Tags: java, android

I am  trying to get the current latitude and longitude using an example i found on the following link: http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/

There are two classes :The first class:

```
package com.example.marinamapseg;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;

public class FallbackLocationTracker  implements LocationTracker, LocationTracker.LocationUpdateListener {


    private boolean isRunning;

    private ProviderLocationTracker gps;
    private ProviderLocationTracker net;

    private LocationUpdateListener listener;

    Location lastLoc;
    long lastTime;

    public FallbackLocationTracker(Context context) {
        gps = new ProviderLocationTracker(context, ProviderLocationTracker.ProviderType.GPS);
        net = new ProviderLocationTracker(context, ProviderLocationTracker.ProviderType.NETWORK);
    }

    public void start(){
        if(isRunning){
            //Already running, do nothing
            return;
        }

        //Start both
        gps.start(this);
        net.start(this);
        isRunning = true;
    }

    public void start(LocationUpdateListener update) {
        start();
        listener = update;
    }


    public void stop(){
        if(isRunning){
            gps.stop();
            net.stop();
            isRunning = false;
            listener = null;
        }
    }

    public boolean hasLocation(){
        //If either has a location, use it
        return gps.hasLocation() || net.hasLocation();
    }

    public boolean hasPossiblyStaleLocation(){
        //If either has a location, use it
        return gps.hasPossiblyStaleLocation() || net.hasPossiblyStaleLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation(){
        Location ret = gps.getLocation();
        if(ret == null){
            ret = net.getLocation();
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public Location getPossiblyStaleLocation(){
        Location ret = gps.getPossiblyStaleLocation();
        if(ret == null){
            ret = net.getPossiblyStaleLocation();
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public void onUpdate(Location oldLoc, long oldTime, Location newLoc, long newTime) {
        boolean update = false;

        //We should update only if there is no last location, the provider is the same, or the provider is more accurate, or the old location is stale
        if(lastLoc == null){
            update = true;
        }
        else if(lastLoc != null && lastLoc.getProvider().equals(newLoc.getProvider())){
            update = true;
        }
        else if(newLoc.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            update = true;
        }
        else if (newTime - lastTime > 5 * 60 * 1000){
            update = true;
        }

        if(update){
            lastLoc = newLoc;
            lastTime = newTime;
            if(listener != null){
                listener.onUpdate(lastLoc, lastTime, newLoc, newTime);                  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second class:

```
package com.example.marinamapseg;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ProviderLocationTracker implements LocationListener, LocationTracker {

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_UPDATE_DISTANCE =  0; 

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_UPDATE_TIME = 0; 

    private LocationManager lm;

    public enum ProviderType{
        NETWORK,
        GPS
    };    
    private String provider;

    private Location lastLocation;
    private long lastTime;

    private boolean isRunning;

    private LocationUpdateListener listener;

    public ProviderLocationTracker(Context context, ProviderType type) {
        lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(type == ProviderType.NETWORK){
            provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        }
        else{
            provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        }
    }

    public void start(){
        if(isRunning){
            //Already running, do nothing
            return;
        }

        //The provider is on, so start getting updates.  Update current location
        isRunning = true;
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, MIN_UPDATE_TIME, MIN_UPDATE_DISTANCE,this);
        lastLocation = null;
        lastTime = 0;
        //lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, MIN_UPDATE_TIME, MIN_UPDATE_DISTANCE,this);
        //return;
    }

    public void start(LocationUpdateListener update) {
        start();
        listener = update;

    }


    public void stop(){
        if(isRunning){
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            isRunning = false;
            listener = null;
        }
    }

    public boolean hasLocation(){
        if(lastLocation == null){
            return false;
        }
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime > 5 * MIN_UPDATE_TIME){
            return false; //stale
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasPossiblyStaleLocation(){
        if(lastLocation != null){
            return true;
        }
        return lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider)!= null;
    }

    public Location getLocation(){
        if(lastLocation == null){
            return null;
        }
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime > 5 * MIN_UPDATE_TIME){
            return null; //stale
        }
        return lastLocation;
    }

    public Location getPossiblyStaleLocation(){
        if(lastLocation != null){
            return lastLocation;
        }
        return lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location newLoc) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(listener != null){
            listener.onUpdate(lastLocation, lastTime, newLoc, now);
        }
        lastLocation = newLoc;
        lastTime = now;
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    }
}
```

What i tried doing was to create an object of the first class and check whether the location can be found as follows:

```
fobj=new FallbackLocationTracker(MainActivity.this);
    fobj.start();
    if(fobj.hasLocation())
    {
        Location locobj=fobj.getLocation();
        current_latitude=locobj.getLatitude();
        current_longitude=locobj.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),current_latitude+" "+current_longitude,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        placemarkersonmap();
    }
```

The issue is as follows:

**The haslocation() method will return false as the lastlocation object is null.But the lastlocation object gets a value only in the onlocationchanged method.So how do i ensure that the onlocationchanged method runs before i call my haslocation method?**

Comment: if its null then call it in your `onLocationChanged`

Comment: @tyczj Can you be a bit more clear pls

Answer (score 3):

> So how do i ensure that the onlocationchanged method runs before i call my haslocation method?

`onLocationChanged()` may never be called. Just because you want a location does not mean that the user has to allow you to get one (e.g., user has both providers disabled). And, just because you want a location does not mean that it is physically possible to get one (e.g., user has GPS disabled and has airplane mode enabled). And, just because you want a location does not mean one will be ready yet.

Hence, your application already needs to deal with not having a location, so add that logic to your app.

You are certainly welcome to also do something more event-driven, starting up some application logic from `onLocationChanged()`, once you have demonstrated you are at least temporarily able to get location fixes.

Comment: I can add logic for checking whether the two providers are enabled or not.That is not the question here.Can you give me atleast a pseudocode demo of how i can get the location in my case?

Comment: @AchuthanM: "I can add logic for checking whether the two providers are enabled or not" -- you still need to handle `null`, for the reasons I outlined in my answer. Having providers be enabled or not is only one reason why you might not get location fixes. "how i can get the location in my case?" -- only start trying to get the location in `onLocationChanged()`. You cannot force the device to give you locations that it cannot obtain (e.g., the user is in a parking garage, and so cannot receive GPS signals and is not getting a reliable mobile connection either).

Comment: @CommonsWare.But my code never works.You are talking as if sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt work.That is not the issue here.When the haslocation method is checked it returns false and i cant proceed further ALWAYS.I just started with the project."only start trying to get the location in onLocationChanged".Please clarify further.

Comment: @AchuthanM: You are calling `hasLocation()` before you have any location fixes. To avoid this, do not call `hasLocation()` until at least one `onLocationChanged()` method invocation has occurred. This is not significantly different than anything else in an event-driven architecture (e.g., do not do X until the user clicks the button, by putting X in the `onClick()` method of an `OnClickListener`). You will also need to deal with the case that your `hasLocation()` method will not be called in a timely fashion, as location fixes are not available, for any number of means, as outlined above.

Comment: "do not call hasLocation() until at least one onLocationChanged() method invocation has occurred", I am new to android can you tell me as how to do it?

Comment: @AchuthanM you dont have to know android to know how to only run something once; use a `boolean`

Comment: "do not call hasLocation() until at least one onLocationChanged() method invocation has occurred".@tyczj. can you tell me how to use a boolean and check atleast one onLocationChanged() method has occured?

Comment: @AchuthanM maybe you should take a step back and actually look at the code you are using so you know what is going on since it sounds like you dont have a clue what is happening with the code

Comment: @tyczi.My question is this.Since we cant check when onlocationchanged method will be called.How do i set a boolean value for its first run and then check the haslocation method?

Comment: override `onLocationChanged` in the `LocationListener`

Comment: @tyczj .I have implemented LocationListener and onlocationchanged method.